# display function Link-list code not working

Tags: singly-linked-list

im trying to add node at the starting of linked list but in my code it only displaying the last element which i have entered only the last element .what is the problem why this is happening

```
 #include <stdio.h>
//node structure
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;

};
```

> //struct

```
//datatype declaration 
typedef struct node node ;
// head pointer which will indicate starting point of link list
node *head;

//create fuction that will insert values into note and its next pointer field 
void create(int num);
//display function will display the link list 
void display();

main()
{

        int num,i,n;

        printf("enter the nno of node to create : ");
        scanf("%d",&n);

        for(i=0;i<n;++i)
        {
            printf("enter data for node %d= ",i+1);
            scanf("%d",&num);
            create(num);



        }
        display();
```

> //display call

```
}
void create(int num)
{
        head=NULL;
        node *temp;
        temp=(node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->data=num;
        temp->next=head;
        head=temp;




return;
}
```

> //function create() end

```
void display()
{
    node *temp1;
    temp1=head;

     while(temp1!=NULL)
    {
        printf("data : %d-> ",temp1->data);
        temp1=temp1->next;


    }

return;
}
```

> //fucntion display() end

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is:

```
head=NULL;
```

Thus your line

```
temp->next=head;
```

always sets the next to be `NULL`. Thus all your lists are
of length one.

I would suggest either declaring `head` to be `static` (and
hence zeroed from the outset),  or intializing `head` in `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Your display function seems fine, your create function should look something like this:

```
    void create(int num)
{
node* temp = new node();

        if(head ==NULL)

        { temp->data = num;
          head = temp;
          head->next =  NULL;
        }
       else if(head->next == NULL)
       {
         temp->data = num;
         head->next = temp;
        }
      else
      {
        node* temp2 = head;
        while(temp2->next !=NULL)
        { temp2 = temp2->next;
        }
        temp->data = num;
        temp2->next = temp;
      }



return;
}
```

This create function above will place the node depending if the list is empty, has one node, or more than one node will insert at Last position. You can now go off this to insert in front of head, or in Link list terms function (InsertBeforeFirst). And of course where you have node* head up top should be initialized to NULL;